# What is Hawkeye's next target?

Tags: dialogue, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

In *The Avengers* (2012), Hawkeye has the following conversation with Loki after being drawn onto his side:

> **Selvig**: The Tesseract is showing me so much. It's more than just
>   knowledge, it's... truth.
>
> **Loki**: I know. What did it show you, Agent Barton?
>
> **Clint Barton**: My next target.
>
> **Loki**: Tell me what you need.
>
> **Clint Barton**: I'll need a distraction.
>
> [Barton grabs his bow]
>
> **Clint Barton**: And an eyeball.

What is his next target refered to in this conversation?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The next target is the iridium meteorite, stored in Germany and controlled by Heinrich Schafer.  The iridium is needed by Eric Selvig to stabilize a portal opened by the Tesseract.

The eyeball (of Henrich Shafer) is required to get past the iris scan security of the facility used to store the iridium.

I suppose that a distraction is required to draw off any attention from The Avengers in case Banner or Stark work out that they need iridium.  Loki manages to provide both the eyeball and distraction at the same time as Shafer is attending some sort of event in the city.

Comment: And so we can infer from this answer that Clint Barton's next target is Henrich Shafer.

Comment: @TylerH Why does "target" have to refer to a person? He's an agent/operative, not an assassin.

Comment: @TylerH: Notice the linked script for what Hawkeye says: _"My next target. (Tell me what you need) I'll need a distraction and an eyeball."_ Henrich Shafer **is that eyeball**, which means that Hawkeye's target isn't Henrich, but Henrich is part of the _supplies_ that Hawkeye needs to get to his target. That means Hawkeye's target is _behind_ that iris scanner that can be unlocked with Shafer's eyeball.

Comment: @TylerH .... no inference involved ... as I say, the target is the iridium.  He talks in 'targets' as he is Hawkeye - his 'superpower' is never missing.

Comment: @iandotkelly That's true, I was thinking the iridium was with Henrich, but he was at the gala where Loki appeared (to get the eyeball and be a distraction). I forgot the Iridium was in a lab elsewhere guarded by several men that Hawkeye assassinates.

Comment: @Walt Hawkeye is not purely an assassin, he is a wetwork operative. More emphasis on the wet while under the mind stone's influence.

Comment: @TylerH Yeah, I wasn't really clear, but my point was just that the target didn't have to be a kill, not that he didn't kill people.